# Show math symbols in gitit

Tags: tex, mathml

I would like to display minor math symbols in gitit wiki.

For example, I can display ⇑ by

```
$\Uparrow$
```

However, other commands of minor symbols, like `\barwedge`, `\notin`, `\nleq`, are not displayed.
Checking the HTML source code, I found that those commands are not converted.

Do I need to install something additionally?

As far as I know, gitit uses texmath in backend.
My gitit wiki is configured to use MathML.